# How to manually apply Transition of color in d3js at path attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While plotting a horizon chart below source is not giving expected result ; 0=1: red, d<0: green; however its running by applying black color only, please enlighten to correct this problem.

```
data=[0.2,1.3,1.1,1.3.0.9]

        var color =
            d3.scale.threshold()
                .domain([0,1])
                  .range(["green", "yellow", "red"]);       
        path.enter().append("path")
                    .style("fill", function (d,i) { return color(i);})
                    .attr("transform", t0)
                    .attr("d", d0);
d3.transition(path)
.style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("transform", t1)
    .attr("d", d1);
```

Comment: I am trying to restrict color based on data selection.
            0<d<1 -> yellow,
             d>=1-> red, 
            d<0-> green.

Comment: I'm seeing that this is your second question about the same subject. However, your code is far from clear to someone without clairvoyant powers. Please, provide a [MCVE], so you can get a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo! https://jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1/ at this fiddle if replace svg by g.select("g").selectAll("path") why its not working properly? It should answer my problem. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `g` element do not exist in this case.

Comment: Many thanks Mikhail, Gerardo!! I am using this URL: https://gist.github.com/syntagmatic/7612dd3c35eeddf51a0b to generate horizon chart and want to control color same as fiddle at jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1. Your help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: fiddle  jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1 is applying color on svg , could you improve the same for path?
 as  Horizon chart at gist.github.com/syntagmatic/7612dd3c35eeddf51a0b is using path to fill color in horizon chart and I am clueless now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply transition to `fill` attribute.

```
  lineGraph
    .data([newValue])
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d); })
```

Look at the demo below based on your code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")

var dataset = [
  [10, 25],
  [10, 75],
   [40, 75],
]

var color =
  d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range(["green", "yellow", "red"]);

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  })
  .interpolate("linear");
  

var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(dataset))
  .attr("fill", "red")

var colorValues = [-1, 0.5, 2];
var colorIndex = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  colorIndex++;
 var newValue = colorValues[(colorIndex + colorValues.length)  % colorValues.length];
  d3.select('#color-value').text(newValue)
  lineGraph
   .data([newValue])
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d); })
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
value: <div id="color-value"></div>
<svg width="500" height="80">
</svg>
```

Comment: Many Thanks Mikhail for answer. 
what is difference if apply ".attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); });" on svg or path ? 
I want to apply logic in source at github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/horizon/horizon.js
Same logic is not impacting at code mentioned in URL, its giving black color, please help.

Comment: @GauravJain I updated my answer. Now `fill` attribute changes. You can change `fill` for both `path` and `svg`, in demo in my answer I change for `path`, here - https://jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1/ for `svg`. But if you apply `fill` attribute on svg, all child elements will get this color.

Comment: Thank you , Mikhil. I applied suggested changes, but unable to control color in github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/horizon/horizon.js, with scale.threshold giving black color and with scale.linear its giving transition of color based on mean value of data. I want to control color based on data.Pls suggest. data structure {Date: MMDDYYYY , Value: 0.01~3.0}
created chart using https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/horizon/horizon.js
var chart = d3.horizon()
.width(width)
.height(height)
.bands(2)
.height(chartheight)
.interpolate("step-after");
svg1.data([data1]).call(chart1);

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I tried fiddle source and at line 35 replaced svg by  g.select("g").selectAll("path") but change in color not applied, please suggest the resolution ?

Comment: @GauravJain "what is difference if apply `.attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); })`?". Attrubute `i` is the index of element. If you want  restrict color based on data selection you should pass data to `color` function: `.attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(d); })`

Comment: Yes, i tried this change but did not get improvement.
 I tried fiddle source and at line 35 replaced svg by g.select("g").selectAll("path") but change in color not applied, please suggest the resolution ?

Comment: while below code instantiate each copy of the path with different transforms to create d3 horizon chart.
          var path = g.select("g").selectAll("path")
          .data(d3.range(0, 2).concat(d3.range(1, bands + 1)));
        path.enter().append("path")
            .transition()
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
            .attr("transform", t0)
            .attr("d", d0);

I am trying to restrict color based on data selection. 0<d<1 -> yellow, d>=1-> red, d<0-> green. But unable to get expected result , please help to identify problem in code.